# How to check a request parameter in JSP using JSTL, especially <c:set> tag?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

I'm trying to parse a request param in my JSP using tags: <c:if> and <c:set>

The parameter is named result, so my variable in jsp is requestScope["result"]

I have two issues:

1. I wanna check two cases: param is null or not,
   I used the following code

   <c:if test='${not empty requestScope["result"]}'>
   <c:set var = "result" value = '${requestScope["result"] }'/>
   </c:if>
   <c:if test='${empty requestScope["result"]}'>
   <c:set var = "result" value = ' not available'/>
   </c:if>

In order to set the result from request in result variable or "not available" value if it is null

This code always shows not available but when i delete the second test, it shows the result corrctly

Also I tried with `'${param.result != null}'` test, it gives the same result.

Thank you in advance

Comment: *FYI:* 1) `null` and `empty` is not the same thing. --- 2) Instead of using two `<c:if>` blocks, use a `<c:switch>` with `<c:when>` and `<c:otherwise>`.

Comment: Or use the ternary operator inside the `value` attribute of a single `<c:set>` element with nothing around it.

Comment: Regarding the response of @Andreas , I understand the difference betwen null and empty, but in my case the both are not working as expected. 
I used the following 
`<c:choose>
     <c:when test='${param.username != null && not empty requestScope["result"]}'>
      <c:set var ="result" value = 'requestScope["result"]'/>
     </c:when>
     <c:otherwise>
      <c:set var ="result" value = 'not available'/>
     </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
`

But id doesn't resolve the issue, result still doesn't contain the "not available" message

@user207421 I will try with that.
Thank you

Comment: If you know the difference, then why do you say *"I wanna check two cases: param is **null**"* but then proceed to write code using **`empty`** instead of null? --- You do understand that the default `scope` for `<c:set>` is **`page`** scope, right? So `requestScope["result"]` is left unchanged. How are you *using* `result` further down? --- Question says *"This code **always** shows not available"* but you comment says *"result **still doesn't** contain the "not available" message"*. Which is it? Is your problem that is shows the message or that it doesn't?

Comment: This question is very ambiguous. Please tell in detail how exactly you've set the desired value. Then we can answer in detail how to correctly get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similiar code and this way works for me:

```java
<c:set var="result" value="${(requestScope['result'] == null || requestScope['result'] eq '') ? 'not available' : ${requestScope['result']}}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jumper for your reply